# Telerik asp.net mvc GridBoundColumnBuilder.ClientTemplate removes '++' chars?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik

This is strange to me but this `cshtml` view:

```
@{ 
    var platformsClientTemplate = @" 
    # var names = []; for(int i=0; i<Platforms.length; i++) { names.push(Platforms[i].Name);} #
    #=  names.join(', ') # ";
}

@(
 Html.Kendo().Grid<ApplicationUserViewModel>()
    .Columns(cols =>
    {
      // ...
      cols.Bound(u => u.Platforms).ClientTemplate(platformsClientTemplate).Width(300);
      // ...
    }
    // ...
 )
```

is transformed to this html for client ("View source"):

```
jQuery(function(){jQuery("#UsersGrid").kendoGrid({"columns":[
// ....
{ title: "mytitle",
 //...
 "template":" # var names = []; for(int i=0; i\u003cPlatforms.length; i  ) { names.push(Platforms[i]);} # #=  names.join(\u0027, \u0027) # "
 }
 //...
]});
```

It looks like '++' removal is bug. How do I enumerate the model in this client template without using new methods like `forEach`?

Comment: surely there's an escape character.. try double backslash..

Comment: how to escape it? Tried `\\+\\+`. Does not work: outputs `\\\\ \\\\ `.

Comment: did you try just using Platforms.join(', ')?

Comment: those are objects with properties. So not going to work. Just updated the question